# Random Font Colors

Tags: php, javascript

I need to color text with 2 or 3 random colors.  How can I do this in PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried already? Remember that StackOverflow isn't a place to get people to do your work for you :)

Comment: DO you want just random colors or do you also want to know how to draw the text with those colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put php code in your css files as well:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
?>

.color1 {
    background-color: <?php echo get_rand_color_code(); ?>;
}

.color2 {
    background-color: <?php echo get_rand_color_code(); ?>;
}

.color3 {
    background-color: <?php echo get_rand_color_code(); ?>;
}
```

the function get_rand_color_code() you'll have to do by yourself. it just have to return a random code like "#afb3e4"

the header in the begining of the file allows it to be called as a css by your html. you should name and call it as a .php file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php" />
```

this is ONE example of how you can do it (:

Answer (score 6):

```
$color = str_pad(sprintf("%x%x%x", rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255)),6,rand(0,9));
echo '<span style="color:'.$color.'">Random Color</span>';
```

Provides random `#<Red><green><blue>` color

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
function getRandomColour() {
    return 'red';      // chosen by fair dice roll
                       // guaranteed to be random
}
```

Courtesy of [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/221/), for those of you who are new around here.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$array = Array('green', 'red', 'blue');
$rand = array_rand($array);
echo $array[$rand]; // This is your random color that you can use in your html
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$color = array(
    1 => "red",
    2 => "blue",
    3 => "green"
); 

echo '<font color="'.$color[rand(1,3)].'">RANDOM TEXT</font>';
echo '<font color="'.$color[rand(1,3)].'">RANDOM TEXT</font>';
echo '<font color="'.$color[rand(1,3)].'">RANDOM TEXT</font>';
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $colors[ rand()%count($colors) ];
```

1 line of code ftw

Answer (score 1):

```
$colors = array();

foreach (range(1, 3) as $i)
{
    foreach (array('red', 'green', 'blue') as $color)
    {
        $colors[$i][$color] = mt_rand(0, 255);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($colors);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [red] => 101
            [green] => 227
            [blue] => 175
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [red] => 78
            [green] => 82
            [blue] => 161
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [red] => 215
            [green] => 237
            [blue] => 135
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)];
        }
        return color;
    }
```

This can be used for text and backgrounds. You can view it working in a div here by clicking the button:
http://sweb1.dmit.nait.ca/~bkoepke1/Random%20Colour%20Generator/