# Random font color

Tags: javascript, css, random

How can I fill text with 2 or 3 random colors?

Comment: You should direct this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You cannot do this with just CSS, you will need Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random font color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057929/random-font-color)

Comment: also you can do it whit server side language such as PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it with javascript.

There are 16777215 colors so...

```
function randomColor() {
    return '#' + ('00000' + (Math.random() * 16777216 << 0).toString(16)).substr(-6);
}
```

There you go - random color generator though some outputted colors might be wee ugly - I warned you!

(there was nice talk about random color generation at [Paul Irish's blog](http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/).)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with CSS and javascript (the code here is for random colors and random sizes):

```
<head>
    <style>
      div {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function randomColors() {
        document.write("<div style='color:#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*4096).toString(16) + ";font-size: " + Math.floor(Math.random()*24+12) + "px;'>");
      }
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
<script>randomColors()</script>Sentence1 </div>
<script>randomColors()</script>Sentence2 </div>
<script>randomColors()</script>Sentence3 </div>
```

etc.

Each Sentence gets its unique color and unique size (from 12px up to 35px).